# How can we set Header for TabNavigator

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

React-Navigation is used in RN navigation. Then there is a tab page using TabNavigator. The position is top. Now the requirement is that there is still some content on the upper part of the tab page. How can this part be displayed?

My idea is to add a header, because this tab navigation is also in a StackNavigator, then this header, how to add?

```
Const tab = TabNavigator (
   {
     Xx: {screen:xxxx},
     Xx:{screen:xxxx}
   },
   {
     ...
   }
);
```

I tried to set the header with navigationOptions in each screen, or in TabNavigator.But it didn't work.

Then, I set it up in an outer StackNavigator. Although there is an effect, there is a problem that every time I jump to this page, the upper header is displayed first, then the lower tab is displayed . There is an left-to-right animation when displayed on iOS, and it is very obvious that the entire page is divided. Is there any solution to this situation? Or is there a problem with my writing?

Answer (score 0):

With this

```
Const tab = TabNavigator (
   {
     Xx1: {screen: tabScreen1},
     Xx2: {screen: tabScreen2}
   },
   {
     ...
   }
);
```

Do this also

```
const tabScreen1 = StackNavigator(
  {
    screen1: { screen: xxxx },
  },
  {
    navigationOptions: {
      gesturesEnabled: false,
    },
  }
);
```

Comment: Where should I use the `tab` ? and  which stacknavigator  dose  the custom header in?

Comment: In this way, there is a problem, the custom header of the tab screen can't get `navigation` props in the outer stacknavigator.